# localhost refuses access on port during Docker tutorial

Tags: linux, http, docker, ssh, localhost

I'm currently getting started with Docker on a Linux VM provided by my university. To get started with docker I'm doing their tutorial (https://docs.docker.com/get-started/part2/#run-the-app). After creating the files the tutorial says to use the command: docker `run -p 4000:80 <name of container>`

This should host the container on http://localhost:4000 because port 80 is mapped to 4000. But unfortunately when I go to localhost this is shown:

> This site is not available.
>   Localhost has refused the connection.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Are you connecting to http://localhost:4000/ from within the LinuxVM?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are running docker on a remote VM and want to connect from your machine browser, you need to replace `localhost` either with the VM hostname or IP. So connect to http://hostname:8080